# Why is tailwind css having no effect?

Tags: tailwind-css, parceljs

No errors, but Tailwind doesn't apply any style:

package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "@vue/cli": "^5.0.0-alpha.2"
},
```

postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = 
{
    plugins: 
    {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = 
{
  purge: [],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: 
  {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: 
  {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body class="dark bg-gray-100">  
    <div class='app' id='app' class="bg-red-500">
        <div class="text-gray-50">hello world</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```css
@import "../../node_modules/tailwindcss/base.css";
@import "../../node_modules/tailwindcss/components.css";
@import "../../node_modules/tailwindcss/utilities.css";
```

Built using: `node ./node_modules/.bin/parcel src/index.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of importing Tailwind's CSS files from the `node_modules` directory, use the `@tailwind` directives as instructed in the [*Include Tailwind in your CSS* section in the Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#include-tailwind-in-your-css):

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then it should work – I just confirmed it on my machine. (Though your build command didn't work for me, so I used `npx parcel src/index.html` instead.)

---

If you take a look at the CSS files that you were importing, you'll see that they contain the same `@tailwind` directives that I mentioned above. I'm not sure, but I think that PostCSS first runs the Tailwind plugin, and after that processes the `@import`s. This would explain why PostCSS didn't process the `@tailwind` directives from the imported CSS files (because it had already run the Tailwind plugin).

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! Doesn't work yet though, still no style, it's still not seeing the Tailwind files for some reason. For instance, in my css file: `@tailwind "NoNSeNsE";` builds without error. As does `@tailwind "../../node_modules/tailwindcss/base";` and `@tailwind "base";`. Is there a verbose way to debug Tailwind or Parcel so I can see exactly what file it's trying to find?

Comment: Oh lol, I had " quotes and you didn't. It works now. Thank you kind sir!